# passing params to update action rspec rails tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Passing params in this way returns the same information as it was before updates.

```
it "PUT Update updates client" do 
    client = FactoryGirl.create(:client)
    put :update, :id => client, :client => { :name => "Rostyk", :email => "new@email.com" }
    expect(client.email).to eq("new@email.com")
    expect(client.name).to eq("Rostyk")
end
```

Comment: Would help a ton to see what you're testing. For all we know it could be that you didn't implement any code to update the client in the action you're testing.

Comment: This is how it happens: `FactoryGirl.create` creates local variable `client`, and a corresponding database record. Then you call `update` action which lives in a separate galaxy from your local variable, not even suspecting of it's existence. In params `update` gets an id of a database record, updates it, and saves back. But your local variable `client` does not change. That is, if you want to see the change, you have to fetch modified record from database, like `client.reload`

Comment: @IvanSelivanov thank you for explanation. client.reload helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:id => client` should be `:id => client.id`

Maybe you need reload object client to see the update:

```
client.reload
expect(client.email).to eq("new@email.com")
expect(client.name).to eq("Rostyk")
```